# Display .GIF from directory

Tags: python

What's the easiest way to open up a .GIF file from my directory and display it in the center of the screen for the user to see.

Comment: Metro? HTML? WinForms? Mac? WPF? Swing? Silverlight? Win32? ASP.Net? SWT? MonoTouch? WP7? GWT? iPhone? AWT? Android? Blackberry? Pencil & Paper?

Comment: python! sorry about that.

Comment: @SLaks I loved "Pencil & Paper"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Linux,

```
import os
os.system('eog {0}'.format(r'path/to/your/gif'))
```